# Please confirm a regex for stripping an optional number off the end of a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have some strings that may or may not have a number at the end, like so:

```
THIS IS A STRING
THIS IS ALSO A STRING      123
```

That is, I'm trying to get the text content of the string, without the *optional* whitespace and number at the end of the string.  Since I'm in php, I'll be using `preg_match` to capture the text in front of the spaces-and-number, thus the capture group around the initial content. There are no constraints on the amount of whitespace and the number of digits in the number; it can be assumed that the number, if it is present, is at the end of the string.

The following seems to work for me:

```
/^(.*?)(\s*\d*?)?$/i
```

but there are surely people out there with more wisdom about regex than I.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: If you will do `$str = preg_replace('/\s*\d*$/', '', $str); ` it should be more fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use

```
  /(\s+\d+)?$/
```

the `\s+` or `\s*` depends if you want to remove numbers from the end of a word like this `THIS IS ALSO A STRING123` With + it wont remove them and it only removes "free" numbers like this: `THIS IS ALSO A STRING 123`.  It's not clear in the question which is acceptable.

[Test It](https://regex101.com/r/fK20BJ/3)

The only reason the capture group is needed is because the `\s` should only be replaced if there were numbers too (maybe).

Something that made me think of is you could even do this `\d*$|\s*$` but the order is important, because first it will remove `\d` then it will trim the end.  And the next logical thing would be to do `^\s*|\d*$|\s*$` and trim both sides.  Now you don't need to do `trim` on it.

[Test That](https://regex101.com/r/fK20BJ/5)

With `preg_replace` there is no need to capture and replace the beginning of the string, you only need to match what you want to replace.

**UPDATE**

Here is a full up example

```
//replaces only free numbers
$str = 'THIS IS ALSO A STRING      123';
echo preg_replace('/(\s+\d+)?$/', '', $str); 
//output: 'THIS IS ALSO A STRING'

//does not trim
$str = '   THIS IS ALSO A STRING      123   ';
echo preg_replace('/(\s+\d+)?$/', '', $str); 
//output: '   THIS IS ALSO A STRING   '

//does NOT strip numbers from the end of a word
$str = 'THIS IS ALSO A STRING123';
echo preg_replace('/(\s+\d+)?$/', '', $str); 
//output: 'THIS IS ALSO A STRING123'

//same as above except DOES strip numbers from the end of a word
$str = 'THIS IS ALSO A STRING123';
echo preg_replace('/(\s+\d+)?$/', '', $str); 
//output: 'THIS IS ALSO A STRING'

//same as the last one except trims both sides
$str = '   THIS IS ALSO A STRING123   ';
echo preg_replace('^\s*|\d*$|\s*$', '', $str); 
//output: 'THIS IS ALSO A STRING'

//using preg_match
$str = 'THIS IS ALSO A STRING   123';
echo preg_match('/(.+?)(\s*\d+)?$/', $str, $match); 
echo $match[1];
//output: 'THIS IS ALSO A STRING'
echo $match[2];
//output: '   123'

//same as above except also captures the numbers without whitespace
//wont match 'THIS IS ALSO A STRING   123  ' <-- ending white space
$str = 'THIS IS ALSO A STRING   123';
echo preg_match('/(.+?)(?:\s*(\d+))?$/', $str, $match); 
echo $match[1];
//output: 'THIS IS ALSO A STRING'
echo $match[2];
//output: '123'

//same as above except adds something like trimming
$str = '  THIS IS ALSO A STRING   123  ';
echo preg_match('/\s*(.+?)(?:\s*(\d+))?\s*$/', $str, $match); 
echo $match[1];
//output: 'THIS IS ALSO A STRING'
echo $match[2];
//output: '123'
```

Hope that helps, it really depends on how flexible you need to be and "exactly" what you want to do.

Comment: I see that matching the spaces-plus-numbers part, but what I really want, moving forward, is the textual string, not the spaces-plus-numbers part. (-1 to me for not being clear; edit to post coming.)  That's why I had the initial `(.*?)` group.  Does this change your advice?

Comment: it depends if you are talking about `preg_replace` or `preg_match`.  With `preg_match` you would need that, but with `preg_replace` then that is all you are left with.

Comment: Thanks to all!  I'm currently considering this a great example of how easy it is get stuck in one level of the problem and miss the bigger picture.  Answer goes to ArtisticPhoenix for directly answering the question (and for a ton of effort), but a strong honorable mention to Don't Panic for seeing the real issue -- yes, the rtrim as specified will, for my situation work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like just using `rtrim` could also be a possibility.

```
$string = rtrim($string, ' 0123456789');
```

Should be fine unless the end of the string before the spaces/digits ends in a number, this would strip that off as well.

Comment: If I could pick two answers as "correct", I would have...  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You may use this regex:

```
[[:blank:][:digit:]]*$
```